# Should a WebAPI Precondition check occur after entity validation?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, web-standards

[RFC 7232 Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.4) Says the following:

> Except when excluded below, a recipient cache or origin server MUST
> evaluate received request preconditions after it has successfully
> performed its normal request checks and just before it would perform
> the action associated with the request method.  A server MUST ignore
> all received preconditions if its response to the same request
> without those conditions would have been a status code other than a
> 2xx (Successful) or 412 (Precondition Failed).

My API will perform entity validation before it calls to persist it to the DB. This could cause the server to reply with a 422 (or other 4xx).

Likewise, my validation layer could pass and the DB validation could fail (some bug where I don't check foreign keys, maybe) and this would raise a 5xx.

If I read the RFC correctly, any response **that I could anticipate** like my validations which would return 4xx should occurr **before** I check the precondition. Is that right?

But my actual exceptions (probably returning 5xx) can't be prechecked.